# Performance analysis in gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi all,
I'm interested to know if there is a possibility to conduct a performance analysis within the robot simulation environment. Can you please provide me any pointer?

Kind regards,
Lorenzo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16180/performance-analysis-in-gazebo/) by [lorenzo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3248/lorenzo/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-05-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sloretz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1290/sloretz/) on 2017-05-17**:
What kind of performance are you interested in? Simulator RAM/CPU usage, or some metrics about the robot being simulated?

**Comment by [lorenzo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3248/lorenzo/) on 2017-05-18**:
I'm interested in canonical performance metrics like response time and so on. In this case it is possible to define a task or a set of task and the framework can measure the time spent by the "system" (one or more robots) to complete all the tasks ?? or the number of task completed in a certain time interval ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Not sure it is what you need, but building gazebo from source, you get access to GTest regression tools and can run different tests related to rendering, physics engine, etc. You could load your models in a test and run it. Take a look at the test section in this link :

http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=contrib_code&cat=development#WriteTests

The advantage there would be to automate testing and then just change your SDF parameters and restart testing.

---

Originally posted by [dbrodeur](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3119/dbrodeur/) with karma: 38 on 2017-05-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0